# Finding a phrase in a string variable

Tags: excel, vba, substring

I am trying to find a phrase inside of a variable that contains html. I then want to replace it with a new phrase.

I tried InStr but the phrase is not found. I also tried using wildcards at tht beginning and end of the phrase. I also tried doing an if  like  also with and without wildcards.

The purpose is to allow a tester to do a batch change on expected results and/or test steps by entering a sentence or phrase they want changed.

The only problem I'm having is being able to programmatically find the sentence within the variable. 
Problem area is in bold

```
Dim qcURL As String
Dim qcID As String
Dim qcPWD As String
Dim qcDomain As String
Dim qcProject As String
Dim preActVal As String
Dim postActVal As String
Dim FindSt As String
Dim currentString As String
Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
'Toggle debugging mode'
Dim isDebugOn As Boolean
isDebugOn = True   'set to true to turn off Active X
''On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
FOLDER_PATH = "BAT\PC2P - Claims - Med"
Set thisSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ShellUpdater")
TestID = thisSheet.Range("B1").Value
stField = thisSheet.Range("B2").Value
**FindSt = thisSheet.Range("B3").Value**
ReplaceSt = thisSheet.Range("B4").Value
testLocation = thisSheet.Range("B5").Value

'ActiveX Forms
   If isDebugOn = False Then
       'qcURL = GetOptionMetric("qcURL", 1, "Enter ALM URL")   ''popup to get url from user
       qcURL = "<<URL>>"
    'qcDomain = GetOptionMetric("qcDomain", 1, "Enter your ALM Domain")     
''popup to get domain from user
       qcDomain = "<<DOMAIN>>"
    'qcProject = GetOptionMetric("qcProject", 1, "Enter your ALM Project")      
''popup to get project from user
       qcProject = "<<PROJECT>>"
       qcID = GetOptionMetric("qcID", 1, "Enter your ALM MSID")
       qcPWD = GetOptionPassword("qcPWD", 1, "Enter your ALM Password")
   Else
       qcURL = "<<URL>>"
       qcID = "<<USERNAME>>"
       qcDomain = "<<DOMAIN>>"
       qcProject = "<<PROJECT>>"
       qcPWD = InputBox("THIS IS IN DEEBUG MODE")
       If qcPWD = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
       If qcPWD = "" Then Exit Sub
   End If
'END ActiveX Forms

'Connect to ALM
Set tdConnection = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
tdConnection.InitConnectionEx qcURL
tdConnection.Login qcID, qcPWD
tdConnection.Connect qcDomain, qcProject

''Check if batch updating or single case
Dim testObject As ITest

   If InStr(TestID, "All") > 0 Then
       Dim TestFact As testFactory
       Set tMng = tdConnection.TreeManager
       Set srcFolder = tMng.NodeByPath("Subject\" & testLocation)
       Set tstFact = srcFolder.testFactory
       Set tstList = tstFact.NewList("")

       For Each shellTest In tstList
           Set DSFact = shellTest.DesignStepFactory.NewList("")

           For Each dStep In DSFact

               Select Case stField
                   Case "StepExpectedResult"
                    **currentString = dStep.StepExpectedResult**
                    **stposition = InStr(currentString, FindSt)**
                       If stposition > 0 Then
                           dStep.StepExpectedResult = preActVal & Replace(currentString, FindSt, ReplaceSt) & postActVal
                       End If
                   Case "StepDescription"
                       currentString = dStep.StepDescription
                       stposition = InStr(currentString, FindSt)
                       If stposition > 0 Then
                           dStep.StepDescription = preActVal & Replace(currentString, FindSt, ReplaceSt) & postActVal
                       End If
               End Select

            dStep.Post
        Next dStep

    Next shellTest

Else
    Dim myTest
    'Find the Test in test plan
    Set thisTest = GetTest(Trim(TestID), testLocation, "\")
    Set myTest = tdConnection.testFactory.Item(TestID)
End If
```

Comment: Can you please add the code you've tried so far so we can see what kind of variables, data, etc. that you're working with?

Comment: If your code isn't working, it's hard for us to help you without seeing it. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the specific problem you're facing.

Comment: FindSt = thisSheet.Range("B3").Value '"but also need rendering provider first name
"
ReplaceSt = thisSheet.Range("B4").Value '<<<!Renderingproviderfirstname>>>
...
currentString = dStep.StepExpectedResult
stPosition = InStr(currentString, FindSt)

Comment: Please edit the question itself to show the code.

Comment: Thanks for editing, but what you're trying to achieve is still unclear. Please read [mcve].

Comment: What's wrong with `Replace()`?

Comment: And I believe your issue with `InStr()` is that the 1st argument is an integer

Comment: the first int is optional. it happens with replace also. Although the below works just fine. I'm stumped

Sub test()
Dim FindSt, currentString As String
Dim test, stposition As Integer
FindSt = "but also need rendering provider first name"
currentString = "All fields populate from the correctly populated provider<<<!Renderingproviderlastname>>>, but also need rendering provider first name"
stposition = InStr(currentString, FindSt)
End Sub

Comment: You really need to clarify this. It's almost impossible to unpack what you're asking with in-line code in comments and more than 80 lines of code in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Sub replace_string()

    FindSt = "but also need rendering provider first name"
    ReplaceString = "I LIKE BANANAS"

    currentString = "All fields populate from the correctly populated provider<<<\!Renderingproviderlastname>>>, but also need rendering provider first name"
    stPosition = Replace(currentString, FindSt, ReplaceString)

    MsgBox stPosition

    End Sub
```